# Specific Event for Opening Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to replicate FireFox preference of delaying tab loading "Options > General > "Don't load tabs until selected" as an extension in Chrome.

Basically, I was trying to use WebRequest (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html) but I am running into two issues:

1) I need to hook into an event to block all requests for open tabs initially. Currently, it seems that only select tabs are blocked while others load when Chrome.app opens.

2) Unregister my webRequest onBeforeRequest event after the initial blocking of tabs. This is only the behavior I need when the initial app load happens.

I already understand how to reload tabs on focus.